# Can't visit many websites except a few(google, wikipedia, yahoo)

Tags: wireless-networking, browser, ethernet, internet-connection

My internet hasn't worked normally since yesterday.

I can't visit a lot of websites, such as `amazon.com`, `nba.com` & my school website. I can visit `Google`, `Gmail`, `Facebook`, `Wikipedia`, `Yahoo` etc & it seems that those are the only website I can visit.

So the modem should be fine. The problem exist across more than one device, on any web browser(*I cleared the browser cache as well)*, different operating system(`my cellphone(iOS), OSX, Ubuntu`).

So the problem should not be in computer or cellphone. Plus these device works well under other wifi network.

I've tried resetting my modem many times. It worked for a short period of time, several minutes to a couple of hours, but then the same problem occurred again. I've called `Comcast` several times and they checked that the modem they provide is fine, and no firewall issues.

My operating system is `Ubuntu 14.04`. I tried pinging websites that I can't visit, data loss was 100%, while pinging `google.com` or `Wikipedia.com` is normal.

I've no idea how I should even start tackling this problem. Can anyone help me ?

**Update:** I tried the suggestion from the top answer of [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627899/nameserver-127-0-1-1-in-resolv-conf-wont-go-away)(same as @Agu V suggested below, changing DNS to 8.8.4.4 and 8.8.8.8), but it doesn't work for me. The problem stays the same.

**Update2:** I forgot to mention that Comcast gave me a new modem for replacement but the problem still persist. And also, if I use vpn connecting to my school, then I can access the internet normally.

What else can I try? Thanks again

Comment: Sounds like a dns problem.

Comment: @yoyo_fun: Thanks. I just tried changing the DNS address as in the Update I just added. Do you know what else I can try? I'm clueless now. Thanks.

Comment: @Stone If your problem persists across more than one device and it was working for some time after you did reset modem clearly proves modem/router provided by Comcast isn't working right. If they can't see this or don't they don't want to accept it cancel the service. & do you have router and a modem or a router+modem ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Thanks for the reply. I think I have just a modem+router because there's only one box, if that's what you meant. And actually Comcast gave me a new modem for replacement but the problem still persist. One more piece information, the problem went away if I use vpn connected to my school. Hope that might give more insight. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the dns from the router.

Example:  Google DNS service

```
Use the IP addresses 8.8.8.8 
and 8.8.4.4 as your DNS servers.
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I guess what you suggested is the top answer of [this thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/627899/nameserver-127-0-1-1-in-resolv-conf-wont-go-away). I tried but it didn't work, problem stays the same. What else can I try? Thanks.